# How to extract images of post and pages excluding header and logo image in wordpress?

Tags: php, plugins, wordpress

I have tried this code to get all images from media library and i am sucessfully getting the source urls of all the images but now i want to exclude all the unwanted images like logo, header images ,etc ...

In short i want to extract all images attached to posts and pages ..

```
if(is_single() || is_page() || is_home() ){  
          global $post;  

$query_images_args = array(
     'post_type' => 'attachment', 'post_mime_type' =>'image', 'post_status' => 'inherit', 'posts_per_page' => -1,'numberposts' => 1
 );

 $query_images = new WP_Query( $query_images_args );
 $images = array();
         foreach ( $query_images->posts as $image) {
         $images[]= wp_get_attachment_url( $image->ID );

         }
            echo "<pre>";
             print_r($images);
             echo "</pre>";
```

My output 
Here the first image is a header image which is unwanted for me ..How to exclude it ..I have tried using attachment size but it cant be unique all the time .. Have a look at it

```
Array
(
    [0] => http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/AboutUsSlider.jpg
    [1] => http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/7325996116_9995f40082_n.jpg
    [2] => http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/6310273151_31b2d7bebe.jpg
    [3] => http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/4764924205_ce7470f15a.jpg
    [4] => http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/2166105529_70dd50ef4b_n.jpg
    [5] => http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/1494822863_aca097ada7.jpg
    [6] => http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/1385429771_453bc19702.jpg
)
```

Answer (score 0):

From this point you may want to specify what you would like to filter.

```
    $images[]= wp_get_attachment_url( $image->ID );
}
$linkstoremove[] = $linksyouwanttoremove;
//remove unwanted images
$filtered_images = array_filter($images, $linkstoremove);
//set data sequence
$filtered_images = array_values($filtered_images);
print_r($filtered_images);
```

Answer (score 0):

Query the db and fetch the posts, then apply any filters and extract from each post and/or image all the images that are within those posts. For example:

```
    $my_images = array();
    $query_images_args = array(
     'post_type' => 'attachment', 'post_mime_type' =>'image', 'post_status' => 'inherit', 'posts_per_page' => -1,'numberposts' => 1
 );

 $query_images = new WP_Query( $query_images_args );
    while ( $query_images->have_posts() ) : $query_images->the_post();

        $dcontent = apply_filters('the_content', get_the_content()); 
        $dcontent = preg_replace("/\< *[img][^\>]*[.]*\>/i","",$dcontent,1);
        if ( preg_match_all('/<img (.+?)>/', $dcontent, $matches) ) {
                    foreach ($matches[1] as $match) {
                        foreach ( wp_kses_hair($match, array('http')) as $attr)
                            $img[$attr['name']] = $attr['value'];
                            $my_images[] = $img['src'];
                    }
                } 
    endwhile;
```

Not 100% efficient but it works.